# Invert OpacityMask

Tags: wpf, xaml, border, textblock, opacitymask

Consider the following piece of Xaml

```
<Grid Background="Blue">
    <Border Width="100" Height="60" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <Border Background="Red">
            <Border.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush>
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <TextBlock Text="Text"
                                   Foreground="#FF000000"
                                   Background="#00000000"/>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Border.OpacityMask>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

It will look like this because of the OpacityMask whos only non-transparent part is the Foreground of the TextBlock.
[image]

Now if I switch the Colors for Foreground and Background in the TextBlock like this

```
<TextBlock Text="Text"
           Foreground="#00000000"
           Background="#FF000000"/>
```

I get this because the even though the Foreground is transparent the Background behind it is not, resulting in a useless OpacityMask :)
[image]

Is there anyway I can get this? Basically an inverted OpacityMask
[image]

Am I missing some other way to do this here?

**Update**
To clarify, even though my example is about a TextBlock, it could be anything. Ellipse/Image/Path etc. The feature I'm after is "Invert OpacityMask"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use my `HollowTextBlock` which is different answer to the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559748/exclude-label-text-from-border/4570435):

```
<Grid Background="Blue">
    <Border Width="100" Height="60" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <Border Background="Red">
            <Border.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <local:HollowTextBlock Width="200" Height="50" Text="Text" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Border.OpacityMask>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**Update:**

Here is a more fleshed out version of `HollowTextBlock` with proper measure capability, property value inheritance for the usual text properties, and a new `VerticalTextAlignment` property for centering the text vertically in it's allocated space:

```
public class HollowTextBlock : FrameworkElement
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(HollowTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, new PropertyChangedCallback(HollowTextBlock.OnTextChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(HollowTextBlock.CoerceText)));

    public Brush Background
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
        TextElement.BackgroundProperty.AddOwner(typeof(HollowTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty =
        TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(typeof(HollowTextBlock));

    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get { return (FontFamily)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty =
        TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.AddOwner(typeof(HollowTextBlock));

    public FontStyle FontStyle
    {
        get { return (FontStyle)GetValue(FontStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStyleProperty =
        TextElement.FontStyleProperty.AddOwner(typeof(HollowTextBlock));

    public FontWeight FontWeight
    {
        get { return (FontWeight)GetValue(FontWeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontWeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty =
        TextElement.FontWeightProperty.AddOwner(typeof(HollowTextBlock));

    public FontStretch FontStretch
    {
        get { return (FontStretch)GetValue(FontStretchProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontStretchProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStretchProperty =
        TextElement.FontStretchProperty.AddOwner(typeof(HollowTextBlock));

    public TextAlignment TextAlignment
    {
        get { return (TextAlignment)GetValue(TextAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextAlignmentProperty =
        Block.TextAlignmentProperty.AddOwner(typeof(HollowTextBlock));

    public VerticalAlignment VerticalTextAlignment
    {
        get { return (VerticalAlignment)GetValue(VerticalTextAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalTextAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalTextAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("VerticalTextAlignment", typeof(VerticalAlignment), typeof(HollowTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(VerticalAlignment.Top, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnTextChanged(d, (string)e.NewValue);
    }

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, string newText)
    {
    }

    private static object CoerceText(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        return baseValue;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var face = new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch);
        var size = FontSize;
        var ft = new FormattedText(Text, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, face, size, Brushes.Black);
        return new Size(ft.Width, ft.Height);
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        var extent = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderSize.Width, RenderSize.Height));
        var face = new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch);
        var size = FontSize;
        var ft = new FormattedText(Text, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, face, size, Brushes.Black);
        var originX = GetHorizontalOrigin(ft.Width, RenderSize.Width);
        var originY = GetVerticalOrigin(ft.Height, RenderSize.Height);
        var hole = ft.BuildGeometry(new Point(originX, originY));
        var combined = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Exclude, extent, hole);
        drawingContext.PushClip(combined);
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Background, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderSize.Width, RenderSize.Height));
        drawingContext.Pop();
    }

    private double GetHorizontalOrigin(double textWidth, double renderWidth)
    {
        switch (TextAlignment)
        {
            case TextAlignment.Center:
                return (renderWidth - textWidth) / 2;
            case TextAlignment.Left:
                return 0;
            case TextAlignment.Right:
                return renderWidth - textWidth;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private double GetVerticalOrigin(double textHeight, double renderHeight)
    {
        switch (VerticalTextAlignment)
        {
            case VerticalAlignment.Center:
                return (renderHeight - textHeight) / 2;
            case VerticalAlignment.Top:
                return 0;
            case VerticalAlignment.Bottom:
                return renderHeight - textHeight;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, very cool! I tried it out and it works :) However, this solution also feels a little "hacky" just like mine did and I wish there was something built into the Framework that would allow you to just use `"InvertOpacityMask="True"` or something. Now, I know there is no such feature and unless someone has a way to work around that I'll mark this as accepted in a couple of days. Thanks